Diferenciar las acepciones de QUILOMBO
En distintas regiones de América "quiilombo" tiene dos acepciones:

Prostíbulo.

Lío, barullo, gresca, desorden.


¿Cómo se diferencia el significado al que se refiere si por el contexto no está claro?

La primera es obsoleta. Asumiendo que no lo fuera, difícilmente comentaría que fue a un prostíbulo.

Me refiero al contexto. Es muy raro que alguien te diga ‘Ayer me metí en un quilombo’ así sin más. Siempre lo va a decir acompañado con algo más. ‘Ayer intenté arreglar un problema con la compu y me metí en un quilombo’ obviamente no va a significar que fue a un prostíbulo para arreglar su problema con la computadora. Por eso para mí esta pregunta es absurda, es como preguntarse cómo distinguir entre los dos sentidos de solo (‘sin compañía’ o ‘solamente’). Mi conclusión es que en general el contexto te permite decidirte por la acepción que corresponde, por eso es absurdo el solotildismo.

Y obviamente no le va a doler la cabeza porque cogió. Coger no da dolor de cabeza. ‘Meterse en un quilombo’ refiere prácticamente siempre a lío.

Originalmente, la palabra "quilombo" significaba "prostíbulo". Luego comenzó a usarse como un sinónimo coloquial de "lío", que es como se la usa actualmente.
Quien va a un prostíbulo, no usa actualmente la palabra "quilombo".
Hoy en día, "estar en / meterse en / tener / armar un quilombo" hace alusión a "estar en / meterse en / tener / armar un lío".

Hay varias: burdel, prostíbulo, no sé es larga la lista. El contexto te da la acepción correcta.

@CAT Un término bastante cómico es "puticlub".

Sí, pero en tono risueño.

Y también tenemos la expresión "irse de putas", sea en un prostíbulo o en otro contexto donde se las pueda encontrar.
